# Setting of max_executing time? 

Tags: php, linux, apache, configuration

I have a server with debian. Server host X vservers (for example 1vserver to pound, second to SQL, third for website X etc). I'm working on one vserver. I have apache2 with one website.
In my php.ini I have max_execution_time = 300 and max_input_time = 249
But when I run script php:

```
 echo '1';
 sleep(16);
 echo '2';
```

I get error Internal Server Error but I don't have any information in error_log.
When I set sleep on 14 sec - this works...

My guess is -> something on debian set time of executing script to 15 sec and ignore setting in php.ini. Our root don't know what this is. Can you help me?

I change my script:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'script_error.log');
ini_set('display_errors', true);
//set_time_limit(1200);
ini_set("max_execution_time",1200);

echo '1';
sleep(16);
echo '2';
?>
```

And I get 500 error and I don't have any info in error_log. If sleep(14) than is ok.

EDIT2:

I change LogLevel na info, debug, notice and warn.And I don't have any information about errror

EDIT3:

Problem is solve. Problem is server pound (http://linux.die.net/man/8/pound). Default value of timeout was setting on 15s. Thank for help for all

Comment: What is max_execution_time according to phpinfo() ?

Comment: from phpinfo(); - I get 300 as global and local

Comment: Nothing. I don't have any information in error_log

Comment: If you have a 500 errors, Apache **must** log something about it somewhere, or your Apache configuration has a big problem.

Comment: I have loglevel warn, notice, debug, info.

And No errors in error log

Comment: What do you mean you "have loglevel warn, notice, debug, info" ? Can you post this config ? It is sufficient to have [LogLevel debug](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#loglevel) as per the doc "When a particular level is specified, messages from all other levels of higher significance will be reported as well". Also: what PHP and Apache version do you have ? on what OS ? Also, is there any .htaccess file in this dir or any parent dir ? You should post as much configuration and logs as possible to complete your question.

Comment: Ok. I found a problem. The problem was configuration of pound - thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max_executing_time is written wrong. It should be: [max_execution_time](http://php.net/max_execution_time).

Use phpinfo() to see what the runtime value is, if it doesn't correspond to the value in the ini then check (again, from phpinfo() output) that you are using the right ini file.

Finnaly, if phpinfo() max_execution_time corresponds to the value in the ini, then maybe something in your code is calling `ini_set('max_execution_time' ...)`.

Comment: Yes. I commit error in name HERE. But if my phpinfo() say: 300 than a believe that ini_set not problem because my script look echo 'x'; sleep(16); and echo 'x'. This all. I copy config - php.ini from server to localhost and script run fine.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code, something calls function 'set_time_limit' or 'ini_set("max_execution_time"...'

Comment: I write in main post whole script.

Answer (score 1):

This might help  you

```
ini_set("max_execution_time",1200);
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction is max_execution_time and not max_executing_time try to change this

Comment: This isn't problem. phpinfo() say -> max_execution_time 300

Answer (score 0):

try to set E_ALL reporting level. just put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

somewhere in the beginning of your php code
it may give you additional info.

Comment: I set
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'script_error.log');
ini_set('display_errors', true);

ale nic nie mam

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

at top of your script, i hope it will work for you