# Incorrect PHP script timeout

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have a script that needs to be launched via browser (user enters FTP login details) and then script uploads some files to remote server.

The problem is that the script time outs exactly after 90 seconds. php.ini has those values:

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
```

I also added those lines to script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Nothing helps, the script still time outs after 90 seconds and "500 Internal Server Error" message is displayed. What else should I look for?

The script is located on a dedicated Linux server with cPanel. Apache suEXEC is enabled. No value "90" in php.ini or httpd.conf files.

Comment: Is there a timeout for the FTP?

Comment: Could you give us this output : `echo ini_get('display_errors');` and `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');` Just to see the actual values. If display_errors is false, then the 500 error may come from a PHP error. Otherwise, it means that the error is at the Apache's level (may be caused by a mod such as fcgi).

Comment: Here's the output:

1 and 300

Answer (score 0):

The ftp_connect function op PHP has a default 90 seconds timeout set.
Try to modify this in your script.

```
resource ftp_connect ( string $host [, int $port = 21 [, int $timeout = 90 ]] )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem couldn't be solved. I'm 100% sure it's not related to FTP because I wrote a new script that has 2 lines of code - sleep(100); echo "ok";. When I launch it, the same 500 error is displayed after 90 seconds.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803714/setting-of-max-executing-time

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this solution didn't help me.